# Как можно создавать SVG фигуры около начала координат и потом помещать на нужное место

Tags: css, svg

Мне нужно некоторое количество похожих фигур SVG разместить в разные места на экране.

Фигуры различаются только размером, углом поворота и цветом, но сам контур одинаковый.

Я хочу нарисовать эти фигуры не сразу на своих местах, используя абсолютные координаты, а нарисовать их в начале координат, и потом переместить их в нужное мне место.

То есть я использую какую-то (какую?) конструкцию языка SVG и говорю поместите мою фигуру в это место.

Можно ли это сделать, если можно то как? Необходимо решение без JavaScript, либо понимание что такое сделать нельзя.

Comment: transform="translate(x, y)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Размещаем прямоугольник `<rect>` и `<circle>` в секции  `<defs>` поэтому фигуры не будут видны до вызова их из хранилища.

`<defs>
<g id="group">
<rect id="rect1" width="20" height="10" fill="blue" />
<circle id="circle1" cx="0" cy="0" r="15" fill="#ff0" />
</g>
</defs>`

Вызов из хранилища, позиционирование, трансформация фигуры, всё это можно сделать с помощью команды `<use>`

```css
rect, circle{
fill:inherit;
stroke:inherit;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="border:1px solid red;"> 
<defs>
<g id="group">
<rect id="rect1" width="20" height="10" fill="blue" />
<circle id="circle1" cx="0" cy="0" r="15" fill="#ff0" />
</g>
</defs>


<use xlink:href="#rect1" x="20" y="5" fill="crimson" />
<use xlink:href="#rect1" x="20" y="5" fill="crimson" transform="scale(2 2.5)" /> 
<use xlink:href="#rect1" x="20" y="5" fill="violet" transform="rotate(45 10 5) scale(1.5 2.5)" />
<use xlink:href="#rect1" x="100" y="20" fill="green" />
<use xlink:href="#rect1" x="120" y="55"  fill="yellowgreen" />
<use xlink:href="#rect1" x="80" y="45" fill="greenyellow" /> 
<use xlink:href="#rect1" x="100" y="20" transform="scale(2)" fill="skyblue" />
<use xlink:href="#rect1" x="100" y="20" transform="scale(1.2) rotate(45)" fill="dodgerblue" />
<use xlink:href="#rect1" x="100" y="20" transform="scale(1) rotate(-45)" />

<use xlink:href="#circle1"  x="80" y="55" fill="greenyellow" />   
<use xlink:href="#circle1"  x="40" y="20" transform="scale(1.2) translate(100 0)" fill="yellowgreen" />   
<use xlink:href="#circle1"  x="40" y="20" transform="scale(0.5) translate(100 0)" fill="yellow" />
<use xlink:href="#circle1"  x="40" y="20" transform="scale(0.5) translate(120 50)" fill="dodgerblue" /> 
<use xlink:href="#circle1"  x="10" y="20" transform="scale(0.7) translate(80 60)" fill="purple" />
</svg>
```

**Обратите внимание**

На стилизацию фигур при использовании команды `<use>` 
Так как при применении команды `<use>` для вызова и клонирования фигур из секции `<defs>` последние попадают, в так называемый `Shadow DOM`, стилизация будет невозможна, если не применить принудительное наследование

`rect, circle{
fill:inherit;
stroke:inherit;
}`